# Prove that $A =\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\neq Y(\omega)\}$ is a event of $\mathcal{F}$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables dened on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and consider the subset of $\Omega$ defined by $A=\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\neq Y(\omega)\}$.   Prove that $A$ is a event of $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:  A "random variable" $X$ is just a measurable function.

An "event" $A$ is just a measurable set.

So the question is an analysis question in disguise.  It's asking if $\{ \omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega) \}$ is an event, i.e., if it's a measurable set.  Well, this set is equal to the set $\{\omega : X(\omega) - Y(\omega) \neq 0\}$.  So, you know $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ are random variables, i.e., measurable functions.  What does that tell you about the function $X - Y$?  Is it measurable?

If so, what does that tell you about $\{\omega : (X-Y)(\omega) \neq 0 \}$?  This set can be written as $\{\omega : (X-Y)(\omega) < 0 \} \cup \{\omega : (X-Y)(\omega) > 0 \}$.  Is this set measurable?  Why or why not?